# Facing " this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB" error while moving code from Gerrit to Github

Tags: git, github, migration, gerrit

I am moving all my projects from Gerrit to Git hub by following the instructions provided [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-move-repository).

While Pushing, I am getting below error

```
git push <git url> --all
Counting objects: 383567, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (125080/125080), done.
Writing objects: 100% (383567/383567), 647.42 MiB | 7.05 MiB/s, done.
Total 383567 (delta 249729), reused 383559 (delta 249723)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (249729/249729), done.
remote: Checking connectivity: 383567, done.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 213456sdfggdas123refsdaw
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File aclocal.m4 is 147.07 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

No file in the entire repository is more than 1 MB and that particular file is about 45KB.
There  are about 40 branches in that project and changes are happening very frequently.

How do I overcome this problem? Will it work if I just install **Git Large File Storage** and try pushing?

*Removing the history is not an option for me*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you the file **in your history** that is too big (`aclocal.m4 is 147.07 MB`).

If you absolutely want to push your history on GitHub, you only have 2 options (that will modify your history):

- You could rewrite it to remove the file if it is not needed and was committed by error.
- Or you could indeed convert all your repository (and your history) to "Git Large File Storage" using `git lfs migrate`. Not just install it...

Answer (score 1):

For your case, if the "aclocal.m4" file is the only one with the ".m4" extension, it should be enough with:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch *.m4'
git push
```